# Convert php date() to mysql datatime type

Tags: php, mysql

My code is like

```
$now = time();
$mysqdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $now);
```

but when i insert it into sql, i can just get 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

```
insert into mytable(current_time) values ('".$mysqldate."');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $now);` do `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $now);
```

with this

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You can also use the `NOW()` function from mysql

so your query will be like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(current_time) VALUES (NOW());
```

**Edit**

In case you want to use an other time that now you should do this:

```
$now = mktime($hour,$minute,$second,$month,$day,$year) 

$mysqldate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $now);
```

and your query will be like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (current_time) VALUES ('" . $mysqldate . "');";
```

NOTE that if you only insert a date that the time from now will be used.

Comment: maybe, but if i wanna use another time like 2001-10-10 10:10:10, i used mktime($hour,$minute,$second,$month,$day,$year) to get a new time, if i wanna translate this to $mysqdate, what could i do?

Answer (score 0):

This line will be fine:

```
$mysqdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: maybe, but if i wanna use another time like 2001-10-10 10:10:10, i used mktime($hour,$minute,$second,$month,$day,$year) to get a new time, if i wanna translate this to $mysqdate, what could i do?

Comment: In that case you are doing right. $mysqdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',mktime($hour,$minute,$second,$month,$day,$year)); otherwise date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date)));

Answer (score 0):

You miss an `l`:

your code:

```
$mysqdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $now);
insert into mytable(current_time) values ('".$mysqldate."');
```

change it to:

```
$mysqldate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $now);
// __^
insert into mytable(current_time) values ('".$mysqldate."');
```